# Php использование инитиализированного класса в дочернем классе

Tags: php

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Требуется использовать инитиализированный класс в дочернем классе. main.php

```
  public function __construct(){
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            include_once 'core/classes/' . $class. '.php';
        });
        //initialze all classes
        $this->debug = new debug("core/cache/cache.log");
        $db = new Database("localhost", "asdasd", "sadasd", "asdasasdad");
    }
```

second.php

```
class Database extends Application{
    private $mysql;
    private $last;
  public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $base, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8'){
      $this->mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $base, $port);
      if ($this->mysql->connect_errno) {
        $this->debug(...);
    }
      $this->mysql->set_charset($charset);
  }
}
```

В гугле сказали что нужно инитиализировать родительский класс в дочернем, но получается замкнутый круг
Достать требуется переменную debug

Comment: Прочитайте про DI, станет понятнее, что вы делаете не так

Comment: Повторюсь __construct не работает как надо

Comment: потому что он кривой, как моя жизнь. Должно быть  public function __construct(mysqli $mysqli, debug $debug) {

Comment: хотя конечно никакой debug в Database сто лет в обед не нужен

Comment: Да, как я не заметил - и **никакого** extends Application! База данных - это не приложение. Вы же не пишете класс Колбаса наследует Холодильнику?

Comment: Если ошибка в запросе то легче посмотреть дебаг

Comment: *Повторюсь __construct не работает как надо* - сильное утверждение, без кода в вопросе я, конечно же, не поверю.

Comment: Решил проблему. Всем спасибо! Помогло решение Ипатьева

Comment: не легче, а сложнее. mysqli должна сама бросать исключения. А потом их уже можно смотреть чем угодно